# Firebase Cloud Function deployment failed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

It seems there is an issue with the Firebase server since the Google Services server downed this December 2020. I can no longer deploy my functions properly, 2 out of 20 deployment only succeed and the rest failed. We already put the issue from Github but it seems there is no team active in the repo.

How can we fixed this as the issue was almost a week now ?

So far this is the latest result after deployment.

```
+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing Desktop\Projects\Firebase Functions\AdRenture Functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged Desktop\Projects\Firebase Functions\AdRenture Functions (20.24 KB) for uploading


There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.
!  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. read ECONNRESET

Error: Server Error. read ECONNRESET
```

Error but not all function which is somewhat common before but now it always occur.

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function acceptRentRequest(us-central1)...
    i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function deleteFacebookUser(us-central1)...
    +  functions[validateCredential(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
    +  functions[deleteFacebookUser(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
    +  functions[approvePartnership(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
    +  functions[getList(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
    !  functions[acceptRentRequest(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
    Server Error. read ECONNRESET
    !  functions[approveRentRequest(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
    Server Error. read ECONNRESET
    !  functions[announcement(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
    Server Error. read ECONNRESET
    
    
    Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
            acceptRentRequest
            announcement
            approveRentRequest
    
    
    To try redeploying those functions, run:
        firebase deploy --only "functions:acceptRentRequest,functions:announcement,functions:approveRentRequest"
    
    
    To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
        firebase deploy --except functions
    
    Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

[image: Error]

[image: Error]

[image: Error]

[image: Error]

[image: Error]

[image: Error]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Yes but unfortunately these images was captured few days ago so I can no longer copy it from my console but still, I can't deploy any changes to my functions as it always get `Server Error. read ECONNRESET`

Comment: Have you contacted Firebase Support?  https://firebase.google.com/support

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will submit a report on that page.

Comment: So far if someone is having same issue like this a temporary alternative is to deploy your updates manually with Google Cloud Console

https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list?authuser=0&project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID